# how do I handle a specific output from systemctl?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, systemctl

I am a beginner with bash/shell scripting and I am trying to handle a specific output that comes from systemctl when a specific service is not found. For example, when I run `systemctl status xyz` the output that returns is `Unit xyz could not be found.` If the service is not found I want to update a variable to hold a string `ServiceName="xyz service not found"`. If the service is found, I don't want to update the variable at all and keep it the same.

This is a part of an effort of trying to find if a specific service is running or not, and store the output from the variable in a csv file that gets shipped to s3 and then I can query the bucket via aws Athena. (I have this implemented already, just providing additional information).

so far I have tried

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
serviceName=$(systemctl status xyz | head -n 1 | cut -c 3-)

if [[ $serviceName$(systemctl status xyz | grep 'could not be found') ]]; then
        serviceName="xyz not found"
else
        serviceName=$(systemctl status xyz | head -n 1 | cut -c 3-)
fi
```

Which returns from running bash test.sh (the name of the file containing the provided code).

```
Unit xyz could not be found.
Unit xyz could not be found.
Unit xyz could not be found.
```

I am running this with other commands, so I would prefer not to exit the entire script on failure.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `systemctl status someservice` this can return these exit status:

| Value | Description in LSB | Use in systemd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "program is running or service is OK" | unit is active |
| 1 | "program is dead and /var/run pid file exists" | unit not failed (used by is-failed) |
| 2 | "program is dead and /var/lock lock file exists" | unused |
| 3 | "program is not running" | unit is not active |
| 4 | "program or service status is unknown" | no such unit |

So in this case we care about `4` exit status. Then you can use this script:

```bash
systemctl status xyz

if [ "$?" -eq 4 ]; then
   serviceName="xyz service not found"
fi
```

---

Btw, in your case this assignment `serviceName=$(systemctl status xyz)` does not work because the variable actually is  empty (because when `systemctl status` fails with `4` this sends the output to `stderr`). So if you want to store both `stderr` too you can use:

```bash
serviceName=$(systemctl status xyz 2>&1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have some additional questions. I tried your solution, but the first line is my variable assignment ```serviceName=$(systemctl status xyz | head -n 1 | cut -c 3-| 2>&1)``` followed by your solution. When I execute the script the variable assignment line gets run and fails the script immediately without evaluating the if block. why is that? TYIA!

Comment: @Sauce I see you have `|` in your commannd, this:  `3-| 2>&1`. Nevertheless removing `|`  would not solution your problem. You should use this: `systemctl status xyz 2>&1 | head -n 1 | cut -c 3-`.  (The `2>&1` goes after `systemctl status xyz` not at the end)

Comment: To underline what was said above, you want to use `2>&1` to merge stdout and stderr of sysctl, not of cut.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon does the stderr get stored into the var serviceName when ran that way? I am sorry, I am just trying to get a better understanding

Comment: @Sauce yes, when you assign to a variable the output of some command  only the `stdout` (file descriptor **1**) gets into the var, however if some error occurs then the output will be sent to `stderr` (file descriptor **2**). So if you want to assign both stdout and stderr you will have to use `2>&1`

Comment: Also if you want to store only the `stderr` you can use something like this: `yourcommand 2>&1 >/dev/null` where `>/dev/null` redirects `stdout` to *nothing*